# store result of execute string into temp table

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, create-table

Within a function I have created a string containing a Select Query as

```
SQLSTR:='select col1,col2 from '||_param1||'_'||_param2||' where col1 like ''%'||_pram3;
```

What I want is to store the result of `SQLSTR` into temporary table as `FilterTable` when after I run the `EXECUTE SQLSTR;` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use the CTAS syntax?

```
SQLSTR := 
    'create temp table FilterTable as select col1,col2 from '
        || quote_ident(_param1 || '_' || _param2) 
        ||' where col1 like ''%' || _param3 || '''';
```

Note that I also added a missing closing quote at the end of the statement, and used `quote_ident()` for the table name, in case it contains special characters.

Comment: will i be able to use the table further in my function for queries that are present variables  like ```SQLSTR```?

Comment: @JayMehta: yes. The temporary table survives until the end of the database session that created it.